# How to check difference between the new and old google cloud function versions in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, version-control

One of my team members deployed a cloud function on April 2nd (version 35), previous version(34) was deployed on March 15th. How can we see what was changed in the version 35 compared to the version 34? Does firebase support this functionality? For context, that team member has left the company and we're trying to see what changes were deployed on April 2nd, version 35 (code is not on github). Any advise is greatly appreciated.

PS. the linked post doesn't answer my question, I don't need to retrieve the source code, I need to compare changes between old and new deployed versions.

Comment: You can get what was deployed previously, but you have to compare them yourself.